# VMware Migration using Migration for Compute Engine - can't registered to migration console

Tags: google-cloud-platform, migration, google-compute-engine

I'm trying to migrate my Virtual Machine from my VMware, I followed all the
prerequisite and requirements configuration to GCP console, I created Migration
managers and set Migration traffic routed over public internet. This is the
documentation I followed [link](https://cloud.google.com/migrate/virtual-machines/docs/5.0/how-to/migrate-connector)

I already accessed Migration managers console and created Token [migration console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vF9G4.png), then I used
the Token to the Migrate for Compute Engine Backend OVA file configuration. and
the Migrate for Compute Engine Backend OVA file was successfully deployed [vmware workstation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8XV2.png) to my
VMware Workstation.

double checked port 443 and [port-test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfMKz.png)IP address have a internet [ping-test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkShC.png) - ALL GOOD

I checked the Migrated for GCE - VMware backend console, the Registration Status
still Not Registered [failed-registered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kf96a.png), please view screen shot images. Thank you

-Created Firewall rules for ingress and egress for TCP port 443
-Verified OS port if Open
-Expecting to registered my M4C ova file to manager console, to proceed for the next step